# Real Inputs not connected

Tags: openmodelica

I have a question similar to the one already [asked](https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/1817-real-inputs-not-connected):

I want to use a model which has several real Inputs (for several sensor signals). But I don't always need all of them. It would be great if modelica would ignore the Inputs that are not connected. Otherwise, I have more variables than equations.

This question was asked in 2015, I wanted to know if there are solutions to the specified problem at the moment.

The solution with adding one more internal variable to each real input is working, but the disadvantages are:

1. the user must specify which inputs are used and which are not.
2. a large number of internal variables with a large number of real inputs
   I hope there is a better solution to this problem...